# Pascal: how to write function without arguments?

Tags: pascal

How to create a pascal function that doesn't have any arguments and returns an array??

Comment: How does having arguments related with the return type? Anyway, you can return a typed array.

Comment: no relation at all, was just to exemplify

Comment: This question has nothing to do with 'functional-programming`. Please read the description of tags before adding them. Just because there is a partial match to a word or phrase in your question does not make the tag automatically apply. Adding irrelevant tags has a tendency to really annoy people who watch for questions in that tag, and it causes the wrong content to show up in search results. Please use *only tags that actually relate to your question*.

Comment: Also, you need to make your question more specific. The answer to what you've asked is "Yes, it is possible." without providing any more details. Is that helpful to you? If not, your question is too vague to be answered, and you need to [edit] to make it more clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
program Foo;
type
        TArray = array[0..9] of integer;
function newArray():TArray;
begin
end;

var
        arr:TArray;
begin
        arr:= newArray();
end.
```

Comment: You already have one 'TArray' to work on in your function: 'newArray'. You don't need the local variable 'arr'.

Comment: true story, but kinda hides some things not writing it for some people to see

Answer (score 0):

It was back then in turbo pascal 7, i don't think it would have changed.

```
type
 IntArray = array of Integer;

function MyArray():IntArray
begin
  MyArray:=[1,2,3];
end;
```

Comment: almost there, i just found out

Comment: Yes, now it has become a typed array.

Comment: Did you actually compile this? It has a few problems. For example, `[1,2,3]` is a set, not an array.